# Failed to import appliance . Could not find a SCSI controller

Tags: virtualbox, vmware

I am on a mac and am trying to import a virtual machine image (.ova file). I try to import the file on a VM and get the following error.

`Could not find a storage controller named 'SCSI Controller'`

Any solutions out there that already exists for this problem.

Comment: this is not the right place to ask this. If you are using Ubuntu go to askubuntu.com or to serverfault ... superuser ...

Answer (score 3):

I got a clue to the answer from here: https://ctors.net/2014/07/17/vmware_to_virtualbox

basically you need to change the virtual disk controller eg change ddb.adapterType from "buslogic" or "lsilogic" to "ide"

However if you don't have VMware to boot the original image and remove the vmware tools and remove the hard disk, you can hack the .ovf file in the .ova file to switch the virtual SCSI controller to an IDE controller.

here's how.

First open the ova archive, lets assume its in the current dir called vm.ova

```
mkdir ./temp
cd temp
tar -xvf ../vm.ova
```

This will extract 3 files, an *.ovf file, a virtual disk *.vmdk file, and a manifest .mf file.

edit the .ovf file, find the SCSI reference, it will be `lsilogicsas` or "buslogic" or "lsilogic".  replace that word with `ide`.

While you are at it you may want to rename all the files so that they don't have spaces or strange chars in the name, this males it more UNIX friendly. Of course if you rename the files you need to modify the references in the .ovf and .mf files.

because you've modified the files the you need to recompute the sha1 values in the .mf file. eg run `sha1sum` to get the value and replace the old ones in the mf file.

```
$ sha1sum vm.ovf
4806ebc2630d9a1325ed555a396c00eadfc72248  vm.ovf
```

now that you've swapped the disk controller and fixed up the manifest's sha1 values you can pack the .ova back up. The files have to be in order inside the archive so do this (use your file names)

```
tar -cvf ../vm-new.ova ./vm.ovf
tar -rvf ../vm-new.ova ./vm.vmdk
tar -rvf ../vm-new.ova ./vm.mf
```

done. Now you can open Virtualbox and click `File -> Import Appliance` then point it at the vm-new.ova file. once done you should be able to start the vm.

hope that helps.

Cheers Karl

Answer (score 0):

I run through a similar problem and I just extracted the`.ova` file and create new VM with my own settings using the `.vmdk` file.

```
tar -xvf vm.ova
vm.ovf
vm.vmdk
vm.mf
```